# mannwhitneyu(x, y) or wilcoxon(x, avg(y))

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Let's say I measure the happyness of my dog over 100 consecutive days. The happyness is measured continuously, and then averaged over 4 bins - (Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Night). This gives us a 2D dataset of shape (4 x 100). I would like to test if my dog is most happy in the evening compared to the other three daily phases. What is the correct way to do that?

My ideas are:

1. Concatenate the remaining 3 phases, and use MannWhitneyU test of 100 vs 300 samples.
2. Average over the remaining 3 phases, and use Wilcoxon test of 100 vs 100 samples.

I feel that my null hypothesis is a bit sloppy. When there are only two phases, it is clear what to do, but when there are more I get a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **joint null hypothesis** that happines is equal *over all four times of day* (i.e., over all four bins), and you do not want to make distributional assumptions about the happiness variable, then a Kruskal Wallis test `kruskal.test()` would be a test of choice to test exactly that. It is a generealization of the Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney-U test for more than two groups.

Note that, in your example, measurements between day times are **nested within days**, which is variance component you might want to explicitly consider in your analysis: there might be days, for example at the weekends, which are overall a bit nicer for your dog. One way to achieve this in a (generalized) linear modelling framework with fixed or random intercepts for day. A simpler approach is to subtract the mean happiness of the day from each measurement before running your analysis, but note that you then implicitly make distributional assumptions.

By the way, depending on the data generating process and distribution you expect for your outcome, running a parametric test/model (ANOVA, GLM, ...) could be a way to lose less information. For example, if your dog rates happines on a scale from 1 to 5, a cumulative logit model could be a good choice.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. (1) I explicitly do not want a null hypothesis of everything being equal. I want to test each phase against all the other and get a sort-of happyness confusion matrix. I know it weakens the statistical significance, but that info is useful to me. (2) Additional day-based variance is a good advice, I should address it at some point. I think a more precise model would be that I only measure happyness on Mondays, and it is not quite clear if some Mondays are different from the other. (3) ANOVA and GLM are both good choices, I can also try those

Comment: (1)  In this case (which is a weird case in my opinion because your are pooling categories  during analysis which you expect to be different), go for the 100 vs. 300 comparisons, no averaging (= kicking out information with no need), but be aware of the multiple comparisons you employ and adjust your decision criteria, e.g. via Bonferroni correction. (2) "only mondays" won't address this issue if there is between-monday variation, and will also tell you nothing about tuesdays. Better to accept the hierarchical nature of your study and reflect in your analysis, the tools are there.

Comment: To address the weirdness: I actually have many dogs. For each phase, I want to find the dogs that are significantly more happy in that phase than in all other phases. I am aware of Bonferroni, but I don't need it here - this analysis is just a proxy to select the dogs I am interested in for a completely different analysis. (2) You are probably right. I need to understand ANOVA better. Problem is that in my field few people actually do it so I have no intuition as to when subtracting daily impact on variance is good and when not